# Monitor Mode on the Intel Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205 (WEP Penetration) On Windows

Tags: networking, drivers, wireshark, wep

Can anyone tell me a way to do WEP hacking (legal, of course) (on my own wireless connection, for the purposes of this question) with Wireshark or similar programs on an Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205?  (Laptop is Acer Aspire 5750-6866.)  According to the programs, I cannot accomplish this (monitor mode) but seeing as it is a fairly recent wireless card (should be able to support this) are there any cracked drivers available or does anyone have the knowledge to make one?

Comment: have you read the FAQ on your card on aircrack-ng's website? http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_drivers&DokuWiki=e43eb4b747ba13b209b89718b64badd7

Comment: Also monitor or promiscuous mode should be available on any card, you need to be able to do packet injection which you will need a different type of card for. unless you want to spend a really long time collecting the required 30k packets or so to crack the WEP key.

Comment: I don't mind the time XD

Comment: Monitor does not appear to be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HAHAHAHA

Ok, the problem was that nowhere in Wireshark's documentation in the software center does it state that it has to be run as root, and it doesn't ask to be run as root by default.  So when it starts up, unless you're logged in as root (which would be unsafe), it won't display any adapters, even ethernet or loopback.

NOTE TO LINUX WIRESHARK USERS: ALWAYS RUN `gksu wireshark`.

Comment: There is a detailed information about required privileges here: http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges

Comment: Right - but that's information on the wiki.  By software center, I meant the Ubuntu software center (I think; it was a long time ago).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the time you need to install WinPCAP from [Here](http://www.winpcap.org/install/default.htm) and also wireshark from [Here](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html). Actually Wireshark should install winpcap anyway and should let you sniff the wireless air around you with that card.

You could also try Netmon: [Here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/netmon/p/downloads.aspx)

Comment: ...unfortunately, I'm not running Windows.  Sorry.  Will Wireshark work if I install that under Linux by itself?

Comment: never mind.  free upvote XD